# @PropertySource to incluide all files in path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

is it possible, or is there a way to declare a @PropertySource so it automatically include all files ending in _config.properties like:

```
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:*_config.properties" })
```

or all .properties inside an specific folder folder

```
@PropertySource(value = { "classpath:somefolder/*.properties" })
```

Answer (score 1):

Spring doesnt have any predefined way for this. But, we can also use the @PropertySources annotation and specify an array of @PropertySource.

```
@PropertySources({
    @PropertySource("classpath:foo.properties"),
    @PropertySource("classpath:bar.properties")
})
public class PropertiesWithJavaConfig {
    //...
}
```

If you want to automatically include those roperty files its possible using yml.

In application-dev.yml, Adding this config allows to inject all the yml that have -dev.yml in them. This can be a list of specific files also. "classpath:/test/test.yml,classpath:/test2/test.yml"

```
application:
  properties:
    locations: "classpath*:/**/*-dev.yml"
```

This helps to get a properties map.

```
@Configuration

public class PropertiesConfig {

private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertiesConfig.class);

@Value("${application.properties.locations}")
private String[] locations;

@Autowired
private ResourceLoader rl;

@Bean
Map<String, Properties> myProperties() {
    return stream(locations)
            .collect(toMap(filename -> filename, this::loadProperties));
}

private Properties loadProperties(final String filename) {

    YamlPropertySourceLoader loader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
    try {
        final Resource[] possiblePropertiesResources = ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(rl).getResources(filename);
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        stream(possiblePropertiesResources)
                .filter(Resource::exists)
                .map(resource1 -> {
                    try {
                        return loader.load(resource1.getFilename(), resource1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }).flatMap(l -> l.stream())
                .forEach(propertySource -> {
                    Map source = ((MapPropertySource) propertySource).getSource();
                    properties.putAll(source);
                });

        return properties;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
}

config
    - application.yml
    - application-dev.yml
    - application-prod.yml
management
    - management-dev.yml
    - management-prod.yml
```

... you get the idea

The component is slightly different

```
@Component
public class PropertiesConfigurer extends     PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer
    implements EnvironmentAware, InitializingBean {

private final static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PropertiesConfigurer.class);

private String[] locations;

@Autowired
private ResourceLoader rl;
private Environment environment;

@Override
public void setEnvironment(Environment environment) {
    // save off Environment for later use
    this.environment = environment;
    super.setEnvironment(environment);
}

@Override
public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
    // Copy property sources to Environment
    MutablePropertySources envPropSources = ((ConfigurableEnvironment) environment).getPropertySources();
    envPropSources.forEach(propertySource -> {
        if (propertySource.containsProperty("application.properties.locations")) {
            locations = ((String) propertySource.getProperty("application.properties.locations")).split(",");
            stream(locations).forEach(filename -> loadProperties(filename).forEach(source ->{
                envPropSources.addFirst(source);
            }));
        }
    });
}


private List<PropertySource> loadProperties(final String filename) {
    YamlPropertySourceLoader loader = new YamlPropertySourceLoader();
    try {
        final Resource[] possiblePropertiesResources = ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(rl).getResources(filename);
        final Properties properties = new Properties();
        return stream(possiblePropertiesResources)
                .filter(Resource::exists)
                .map(resource1 -> {
                    try {
                        return loader.load(resource1.getFilename(), resource1);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        throw new RuntimeException(e);
                    }
                }).flatMap(l -> l.stream())
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I searched about it and I think there is no option for matching the patterns of your config file names so the best I could find out is using the file in @PropertySource like this

```
@PropertySource("file:/path/to/application.properties")
```